# How set pull up for refresh SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, listview

I see very much libraries for ListView pull to refresh. But they are work, when pull from top to down, but how i can do refresh when pull from bottom to up? Can i make this with [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) ? If no, what library i must use? And how do that?

Comment: [easy-swipe-to-refresh-in-android.html?spref=tw](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2014/06/easy-swipe-to-refresh-in-android.html?spref=tw)

Comment: you can override onTouch and implement it

Comment: simply edit any library, most of them uses `onTouch()` event, put you logic in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and to check if the list is at the end use `if ((firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount)` and them simply refresh

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal thanks for the example, but can you please say what library you would use

Comment: [Link 1](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)
[Link 2](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)
[Link 3](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)
[Link 4](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView)
[Link 5](https://github.com/JoeDailey/Android-Simple-Pull-to-Refresh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use chrisbanes 's library: 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh which supports listview, gridview, scrollview, webview ...

To refresh listview from bottom, just set mode for it. Here is an example :

```
PullToRefreshListView ptr= 
  (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
mPullRefreshListView.setMode(Mode.BOTH);    // mode refresh for top and bottom
mPullRefreshListView.setShowIndicator(false); //disable indicator
mPullRefreshListView.setPullLabel("Loading");

 ptr.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
            public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
          //do something when refresh
});
```