# Pull up to refresh using SwiperefreshLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using `SwiperefreshLayout` to refresh `ListView`. I'm done with Pull Down which is quite, but I'm not getting how to use it for Pull Up.Is anybody implemented Pull Up using  `SwiperefreshLayout` or any one having best link for reference..

Answer (score 1):

[Swipe to refresh](https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshListFragment/src/com.example.android.swiperefreshlistfragment/SwipeRefreshListFragment.html)

Go through this link...

Answer (score 0):

Change refresh mode using this,

```
    mPullRefreshListView.setMode(Mode.BOTH) // which ever you want



    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh() {

          ...
          // on refresh goes here.
      }
  }
```

check this [link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26013956/2064336)

Comment: Dude I ask for **Pull Up**